# Is there any way the get the current url in Require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want a project accessible by both web and mobile Android app. Suppose I have required `b.js` in my project. And my `b.js` looks like:

```js
require(['../c'], function(c){
  //my code here
})
```

In my Android app, the path to `c.js` will be `file://somepath/c.js`. Since `b.js` could be written by any clients of web and I have no possibility to upload `c.js` to my local mobile environment. Is there a way to get current requirejs(`b.js`) http path so that I can calculate the complete http path for its dependencies like `c.js`?

Comment: Can't you declare `c` in the config's `paths` section, so that you'll just have to use `require(["c"], function(c) {...});`?

Comment: @sp00m No, we offer an interface for users to write their own js file. We can not force them to import `c` in http way. So we have to do some hacking on mobile side to support this feature.